# Plotting subplots in matplotlib from multiple data frame and standardize axises

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis-labels, subplot

I have 11 data frames in python that have identical columns but split rows by a DateTime year. Here are two examples of my data frames:

```
_2008 = data[(data['fulldate'] > '2007-12-31') & (data['fulldate'] <= '2008-12-31')]
_2009 = data[(data['fulldate'] > '2008-12-31') & (data['fulldate'] <= '2009-12-31')]
```

From these data frames, I create graphs in matplotlib that look like this:
[image]

[image]

using the following code:

```
plt.plot('fulldate','num_recvd', data=_2009, color='black')
plt.title('Number of Requests in 2009')
plt.xlabel('Month', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Number of Requests', fontsize=10)
```

with 'data=_2009' changing depending on the year because the data from each year is contained in separate data frames.

I would like to create one graph with subplots similar to this:

[image]

but cannot figure out how to do so (I have searched other resources for answers).

I would also like to standardize the axis with only the months on the x-axis and the same units on the y-axis (some years have counts up to ~47, while others only have counts up to 1 or 2).

With the code in the first answer I get this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pyplot.subplots`. Here is some demo code. It's much cleaner to first create a field `year` in your data, then group by that `year` and plot.

```
data.fulldate = pd.to_datetime(data.fulldate)
data['year'] = data.fulldate.dt.year

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, sharey=True)
axarr = axarr.flatten()

for i, (name, data_group) in enumerate(data.groupby('year')):
    ax = axarr[i]
    ax.plot('fulldate','num_recvd', data=data_group, color='black')
    ax.set_title('Number of Requests in ' + str(name))
    ax.set_xlabel('Month', fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Number of Requests', fontsize=10)
```

Note the `sharey = True` on the first line: this means that all the y axes will share the same scale.

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the data in a proper array? Right now all the data is in sperate dataframes called '_2008', '_2009", etc.?

Comment: You can get the data in an array like this : `data_arr = [df_2008, df_2009, ... ]`. However, if you show me how you split the data up in the first place, I could likly show you a better way of doing it that would give you an array directly.

Comment: I split the data using these lines `_2008 = data[(data['fulldate'] > '2007-12-31') & (data['fulldate'] <= '2008-12-31')]` from a dataframe called data.

Comment: When running the array I get the following error: `NameError: name 'date_names' is not defined`

Comment: That's because you need to create that array :). Give me a sec, I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: I updated my question with the outcome of your updated code, please let me know what's going wrong.